# Что значит конструкция if (mas[i] - !!a != a[i])

Tags: c++

Недавно начал изучать C++, столкнулся со странной конструкцией условного оператора и не могу понять что он с чем сравнивает

у нас два массива с типом char одинаковой длины, далее он как-то сравнивает символы этих массивов.
И главный вопрос: какие символы должны быть в mas[], чтобы длина строки осталась той же, но условие не выполнилось

```
char mas[] = "qwerty";
char a[] = "J@RODQ";

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)-1; i++) {   
        if (mas[i] - !!a != a[i]) {     // что с чем сравнивается?
            puts("WRONG!");
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конструкция верная, но бессмысленная с практической точки зрения. Подвыражение `!!a` - это применение двух операторов `!` к массиву `a`. В этом контексте массив неявно приводится к типу "указатель" (получается ненулевой указатель), а затем к типу `bool` (ненулевой указатель превращается в `true`). Двойное применение логического отрицания `!` к значению `true` снова дает `true`. Таким образом значение выражения `!!a` - просто `true`. В арифметическом контексте `true` ведет себя эквивалентно значению `1`, то есть ваше условие эквивалентно

```
if (mas[i] - 1 != a[i])
```

Вот и все. Остальной код никакими особенностями не обладает. Почему автор написал `!!a` вместо просто `1` - неизвестно. Скорее всего просто для обфускации кода.

Чтобы условие *ни разу не выполнилось*, надо поместить в строку `mas` символы, коды которых на единицу больше соответствующих кодов символов строки `a`

```
char mas[] = "23456";
char a[] = "12345";
```

Как будет выглядеть строка `mas` для вашего исходного варианта `a` - формально зависит от платформы. Можно записать ее так

```
char a[] = "J@RODQ";
char mas[] = { a[0]+1, a[1]+1, a[2]+1, a[3]+1, a[4]+1, a[5]+1, 0 };
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/iRUs2qi.png

Comment: @Alex78191: Иии?

Comment: компилятор умный

Comment: В задании сказано что менять надо только mas. А не а и mas..

Comment: @AndrioSkur это пояснение по принципу работы условия

Comment: @Ant, если в массиве есть нуль-символ, то там будет `0`, так что заменять на `1` не совсем корректно. `!!` в Javascript применяется как оператор преобразования любой переменной в bool, поэтому, вероятно, автор не обфускацией занимался, он просто «жаваскриптер».

Comment: @ixSci: Не понимаю, о чем вы говорите. Значение выражения `!!a` - константа времени компиляции, всегда `true` и от содержимого массива `a` никак не зависит. Будет нам нуль-символ или нет - значения не имеет.

Comment: @Ant, ошибся. Решил, что там есть скобки, которых нет.

Answer (score 0):

Char это числовая переменная.

`a` - указатель. В C ++ значение nullptr определено как недопустимый указатель. `! Pointer` превращает указатель nullptr в true и указатель non nullptr в false. `! Boolean` превращает true в false и false в true. Он всегда будет работать.

Не думайте, что это «двойной восклицательный знак», думайте об этом как о двух отдельных операторах, один из которых работает на результат другого.
`!(!a)`

Answer (score 0):

Взлом простым перебором:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


void check(const char* mas){
    char a[] = "J@RODQ";
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)-1; i++) {   
        if (mas[i] - !!a != a[i]) {
            puts("WRONG!");
            return;
        }
    }
    puts(mas);
}


int main(){
    std::string answer = "";
    char a[] = "J@RODQ";
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)-1; i++) {
        for(int c=0;c < 1000;c++){
            if (c - !!a != a[i]) {

            } else {
                answer += c;
                break;
            }
       }
    }
    check(answer.c_str());
}
```

P.S. Онлайн компилятор: https://repl.it/I4y0/4 Ответ: "KASPER"

Comment: Я оптимизировал вашу программу https://repl.it/I4y0/7